# Will gelled fuel work in a cat can stove?

Tags: gear, cooking, diy, ultralight

Recently a friend suggested using gelled fuel in a [cat can stove](http://jwbasecamp.com/Articles/SuperCat/index.html) instead of liquid alcohol.  Since a cat can stove works by using pressurization to create the "jets" it seems flawed, but has anyone tried?

Comment: Good question - I haven't tried it but my gut feeling is the same as yours, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gelled alcohol has problems even in its "native" setting of a Sterno can. Gelled alcohol burns at a lower temperature. A standard Sterno can take 20 minutes or longer to boil water and is typically more expensive than liquid alcohol fuel.

[Some good information on different fuel sources for alcohol stoves.](http://zenstoves.net/Stoves.htm#Fuels)

[Information on Sterno.](http://zenstoves.net/Sterno.htm)

Answer (score 2):

If it's an open top cat stove (or any open top container) you can use gel.

If it's a trangia style stove with tiny vents - no. Well, yes you can - the gel will still burn out of the trangia fill hole but it will clog up the vents.